# react-quill, how to set variable in body

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, mern

I'm using react-quill to allow my client to write custom mail in text editor.
But he want to be able to add variables like `{client.name}` or `{booking.date}`.

I tried to add template string like `'Hello ${client.name} ${client.firstName}'` but I don't get the variables, only the text.

Anyone know how can I allow my client to use variable, or if/else or any javascript code ?

Edit: To avoid nefarious people, i'd like to use custom button that show only available variables like this:
[Text editor example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaUgo.png)

For the moment, I use react-hook-form to send data to my API and send email with nodemailer from by backend.
Here is my backend code :
[backend code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAPTp.png)

Here the result I get :
[mail I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jKw9.png)

Here the result I want :
[result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6T0A.png)

Comment: Where do you want to see the replacement happen? How are you handling the text once complete from the client?

Comment: If a button is clicked to submit the text then you just need to search and replace based on your model. If you need conditionals in the text editor, maybe model a value and put the condition handling in the backend. Otherwise, you'll probably need to implement some type of javascript parser in the backend, however, this is going to be a possible attack vector for nefarious people

Comment: How did you display selected fields on react-quill like that ? I'd appreciate if you shared the client-side code. I'm trying to display selected form fields like 'Hello {{full_name}}' on quill. (displaying variable names is sufficient in my case, not the value but the key if that makes sense :))